# How to use stable version of framework Zend 2.2.0?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have just started to explore ZF2 framework for my project. Please note that I have not worked with ZF1 framework also.

**Problem**:

I want to know the way/method/steps to install a stable version Zend framework 2.2.0.

**Things Done**:

I am able to install ZEND skeleton application by following the documentation PDF i.e. from GitHub however I am not able to locate the steps to download zend stable version from site and use it on local. This has downloaded framework is showing version >2.2.0 RC1.
I am not very much sure about how much it is stable since zend framework itself stated it as release candidate.

I have used the steps described in PDF document with downloaded zend framework however after executing composer update and install there were no public directory got installed in root directory.

Please let me know if there is any steps to use stable version of Zend Framework using which I can build my application OR I must have to use 2.2.0 RC1 provided by zend skeleton application from Github.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you try the **composer.phar** ?

Comment: Yes. after downloading the version 2.2.0 from site I have executed "php composer.phar self-update" and "php composer.phar install" commands from project directory but didn't see any thing get added in project directory. I have also made changes in hosts files but on opening in browser it is showing directory structure unlink skeleton application show screen of index controller of application module

Comment: Can you show us your composer.json. Otherwise if you modifiy this composer.json, you have to update after any change with **php composer.phar update**. The composer.phar download himself the files into the vendor dir.

Comment: How I can show composer.json? should I paste the content here?

Comment: I have uploaded this to google drive...https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2owybOlptnxMFdYNGU0YWplRFk/edit... Need to download to view

Answer (score 0):

try this composer.json

```
{
    "name": "zendframework/zendframework",
    "description": "Zend Framework 2",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "zf2"
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "dev-master",
        "zendframework/zend-developer-tools": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/annotations": ">=1.0",
        "ircmaxell/random-lib": "dev-master",
        "ircmaxell/security-lib": "dev-master",
        "ocramius/proxy-manager": "0.3.*",
        "phpunit/PHPUnit": "3.7.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Zend\\": "library/",
            "ZendTest\\": "tests/"
        }
    }
}
```

I prefer to use some stable libraries like:

```
"zendframework/zendframework": "2.1.5",
```

Comment: Thanks for the updated json.
Should I change the value of "zendframework/zendframework" from dev-master to 2.1.5 in composer.json?
I encountered an error on executing  self-update and install command using above composer.json with "dev-master" and "2.1.5"

Link to Screen capture is below 
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2owybOlptnxYUhqY3Y4TmM5aTg/edit
Please note that I have downloaded stable version 2.2.0 from zend site and updated composer.json as above
I am may be doing something wrong since I am working on zend for the first time.

Comment: If you have already install some lib, just use **php composer.phar update**

Comment: i tried above json file with fresh copy of downloaded code but still facing same issue.

Comment: Hi Remi,  
I have downloaded the skeleton application from GitHub and them made changes in composer.json and updated "zendframework/zendframework": "=2.2.0" from "zendframework/zendframework": ">2.2.0rc1" and made rest of the changes as mentioned in tutorial PDF documentation of 2.2.0 framework and showed me the home page correctly as described in documentation.  

I just wanted to confirm that Is changing version in composer.json to point to stable version is correct?

Comment: One more thing on executing install command of composer.phar in project directory I got the message as in image https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2owybOlptnxZkVXT2cyZ3BjS0U/edit

Please see the output of second install command. Could you please let me know how to install these packages? I will also search on google to find the method to install these packages